# MediaPlayer in View doesn't play. Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a local .mov file added to my Xamarin project. I want to play it in a view I added in the Main.storyboard file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using MediaPlayer;

namespace XamarinTest
{
    public partial class heartbeatPage : UIViewController
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer;
    public heartbeatPage (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromFilename("heartAnimation4.mov"));
            moviePlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit;

        heartView = moviePlayer.View; //HeartView is a view I added in the storyboard.

        moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();
        moviePlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try my approach:

```
AVPlayer _player;
AVPlayerLayer _playerLayer;
AVAsset _asset;
AVPlayerItem _playerItem;

_asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("YourClip.mp4"));

_playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(_asset);
_player = new AVPlayer(_playerItem);

RegisterNotification();

_playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(_player);
_playerLayer.Frame = heartView.Frame;
_playerLayer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill;

heartView.Layer.AddSublayer(_playerLayer);

_player.Play();
```

Comment: Thank you! I've got it working using the AVPlayer earlier, but I need to only show the video on a part of the screen, and have text on the rest.